# Prove $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}b_k(x-b)^k $ satisfies $\lim\limits_{x\to b}\dfrac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{(x-b)^n} = 0 $ iff $P_n = T_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials

Prove $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}b_k(x-b)^k$ satisfies $$\lim\limits_{x\to b}\dfrac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{(x-b)^n} = 0 $$ iff $P_n = T_n$ Where $T_n$ is the nth Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $b$.

I know from Taylor's Theorem that $$\lim\limits_{x\to b}\dfrac{f(x)-T_n(x,b)}{(x-b)^n} = 0$$ I can see the forward proof intuitively from Taylor's theorem, but intuition isn't reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assuming $f$ is $n+1$-th continuously differentiable, then
\begin{align}
f(x)=&\ f(b)+f'(b)(x-b)+\ldots+ \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(x-b)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-b)^{n+1}\\
=&\ T_n(x)+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-b)^{n+1}
\end{align}
where $b<\xi(x)<x$. By the hypothesis, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)-P_n(x)}{(x-b)^n} = \frac{T_n(x)-P_n(x)}{(x-b)^n}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-b).
\end{align} 
Since the left hand side tends to zero as $x\rightarrow  b$ then so does the right hand side. In particular, since 
\begin{align}
\left\|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-b)^{n+1}\right\|\leq M|x-b|\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $x\rightarrow b$, then 
\begin{align}
\frac{T_n(x)-P_n(x)}{(x-b)^n} \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $x\rightarrow b$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful! How exactly does this prove $T_n(x) = P_n(x)$? I see the denominator in the last line tends to $0$, but couldnt that mean the numerator tends to anything? Could I use l'hopital to prove $T_n(x) = P_n(x)$ in the last step?

Comment: @t.perez suppose they are not equal, then what can you conclude?

Comment: you could  conclude that the limit DNE if they're not equal since the denominator would equal 0, so they must be equal. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Seems like you got it.

Comment: thank you so much! you are very helpful